# Non Distributed Data _ Spring Batch Partitioner

Tags: spring-batch, batch-processing, partitioning, partition, database-partitioning

Just take a case where I am reading data from a Database with conditions (millions of rows), doing some business on data and then updating it.

I am using a Column Range Partitioner ( Id column ) taking Min and Max Ids to process, and creating partitions with max-min/gridSize.

Now imagine i have the Ids 1, 22, 23, 24, 30 with gridSize =3 , with that logic i will have 3 partitions:

**partition1** processing Id 1

**partition2** processing 0 Rows

**partition3** processing 22, 23, 24 and 30

With millions of Data, parallel processing like this isn't useful, and trying to recover all the data in a single request for implementing distributed partitioning takes forever..

What's the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ColumnRangePartitioner` showed in the examples states that you need an evenly distributed column for it to be effective (as you have noted). Instead, you can typically add a row number to your query and partition on that since it will be a sequence over the results.

An example of the SQL would look something like this (for MySQL):

```sql
SELECT F.*, 
       @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank 
FROM FOO F, 
     (SELECT @rownum := 0) r;
```

With that, the column `rank` would be a sequence autogenerated each time you run the query. From that value, you could partition the dataset. Since this isn't persistent, you'd need to do some gymnastics to get the right ids, but the basic logic of your `Partitioner` implementation would look something like this:

1. Run count query to find out how many records there are in your data set.
2. Run a query using above technique to figure out what the db id is for the start and the end of each partition range. This will give you the ids to filter by per partition.
3. Create a partition for each pair (start/end) using the actual db ids.
4. Setup your `ItemReader` to read the items only within the range of the db ids provided.

Comment: What do you mean add another column to the Table and set it sequentially before starting the job ?Coud you explain more please ?

Comment: I thought it would be possible without creating a staging table and a rank column , but that's what i did eventually . Thank you for your answer